# Create simple SOAP WEB SERVICE in java using axis2?

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis

any one here have idea about creating SOAP Web service by following steps.

1. Creating Web service Class
2. Creating arr file using ant build file and
3. Publish and access web service using web service client.

I'm new to SOAP Web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Web Service with from a class using Axis2 (Code-first approach).

You can download the [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi) distribution and refer samples

Refer following guide on creating a Web Service from a POJO (Plain Old Java Object).

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/pojoguide.html

You can create clients using the WSDL.

Refer: 
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html